# Wireless option missing in network settings

Tags: wireless, networking

When I go to click on NETWORK in the System Settings menu, I have is Network Proxy and Wired Network but no Wireless option.
My laptop is Hp pavilion g6.

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Could you verify with [how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx) to confime which wireless device you have.

Comment: running this lspci | grep Network gives

07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

and lspci -vnn | grep Network

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]

Comment: @Sneetsher Could you tell me what  should i do to enable bluetooth.

Comment: Happy to hear that, So we can count this as duplicate?

Comment: For Bluetooth run lsusb to see if you can know your device. Try search for previous question same device or same laptop. If nothing please submit new question.

Comment: output of lsusb   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b34f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd

Comment: Sorry, It is not on USB list. We cannot carry on here (out of topic).
Try to know which device you have if have other OS installed...or from exact specifications. As I see from official site there are more than 3 options for bluetooth. Then try open new Question if no similar case.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your wireless is enabled. Click the wrench icon on the right corner of the screen and see whether you can see the option wireless. If u can see then click on it and choose enable.